# Using for loop to put objects as value in HashMap

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have a HashMap and I created a method to add objects to that HashMap, but I am getting a NullPointerException

```
private HashMap<String, Player> createPlayerStatsHashMap(List<String> listPlayerNames, PlayerScoresDatabase db) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listPlayerNames.size(); i++) {
        Player player = new Player(i, listPlayerNames.get(i));
        player.setWinPercentage(db.getWinPercentage(listPlayerNames.get(i)));
        player.setBestGame(db.getBestGame(listPlayerNames.get(i)));
        player.setWorstGame(db.getWorstGame(listPlayerNames.get(i)));
        player.setRivalPlayer(db.getRivalPlayer(listPlayerNames.get(i)));
        // Each of these Logs returns the correct value
        Log.d(StartingPageActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "PlayerStatsActivity createPlayerStatsHashMap player name: " + player.getPlayerName());
        Log.d(StartingPageActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "PlayerStatsActivity createPlayerStatsHashMap player winpercent: " + player.getWinPercentage());
        Log.d(StartingPageActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "PlayerStatsActivity createPlayerStatsHashMap player bestgame: " + player.getBestGame());
        Log.d(StartingPageActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "PlayerStatsActivity createPlayerStatsHashMap player worstgame: " + player.getWorstGame());

        // This is where the NullPointerException occurs
        listPlayerStats.put(listPlayerNames.get(i), player); // this is line 55

    }
    return listPlayerStats;
}
```

Here's the Stacktrace:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.HashMap.put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                     at com.brbecker.tabletopcompanion.activities.PlayerStatsActivity.createPlayerStatsHashMap(PlayerStatsActivity.java:55)
>                                                                                     at com.brbecker.tabletopcompanion.activities.PlayerStatsActivity.onCreate(PlayerStatsActivity.java:33)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)

Thanks!

Comment: Where is NPE coming from when you debug?

Comment: Don't use raw types. That is not a correct constructor for `HashMap`. That is not a correct constructor for `Object`, which also doesn't have those methods. It looks to me like that `list.get(i)` is returning `null`, assuming that the obvious compiler errors are corrected in your actual code, which you should show.

Comment: MyObject object = new MyObject(...) not Object

Comment: Please add the message from exception.printStack.  I only can find two points may throw NPE in this line: hm is null or list is null, but it seems impossible indeed.

Comment: Can you tell me name of class which you imported for SQLDatabase.

Comment: I replaced code I had with the actual code used. I used a custom SQLDatabase helper named PlayerStatsDatabase that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. Everything works up until I call listPlayerStats.put(listPlayerNames.get(i), player);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is missing:

```
listPlayerStats = new HashmMap<>();
```

Hence the variable is null causing the error.

There is an indecision in the code:

- either make the method void, altering the field `listPlayerStats`, or
- use a local variable in the method, and return that, assign the result to field `listPlayerStats`.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks!